# Finding the sum of columns in a Two Dimensional Array with rows of different lengths

Tags: java, arrays

So i'm having a bit of trouble with my code in returning the sum of the columns in a two dimensional array with rows of different lengths. For example a 2X2 array works perfectly to calculate the sum of the columns. But if I were to have for example a 2X3 array it gives me an out of bounds error. I want it to work for any numbers given by the user for rows and columns not just a fixed number that I said as an example. Can somebody help me resolve this issue? much thanks!

here is my code:

```
public static void columnSum(int[][]anArray) {
    int totalcol = 0;
    for(int col =0; col < anArray.length; col++){
        totalcol = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < anArray[col].length; row++) {
            totalcol += anArray[row][col];
        }
    System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + totalcol);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indices are flipped.  Your `for` loops are written for column-major ordering, but your totalizer is written for row-major order.  You need to reverse one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the for loop

```
    for(int row = 0; row < anArray[col].length; row++) {
        totalcol += anArray[row][col];
    }
```

If the array is 2X3 then in this for loop when you are using the `col = 0` Then `anArray[col].length` returns value 3. So your `row` variable can have values 0 - 2 in the for loop. So when the value of `row` is 2 and the value of `column` is 0 (as stated earlier), `anArray[row][col]` will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` as `anArray[2][0]` does not exists.

So try out this instead:

```
    for(int row = 0; row < anArray.length; row++) {
        totalcol += anArray[row][col];
    }
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) of the array elements. There are two possiblities:

1. `anArray[i][j]` represents the element at row `i` and column `j` (row-major)
2. `anArray[i][j]` represents the element at column `i` and row `j` (column-major)

The easier task to solve is finding column sums in a column-major array, or---completely equivalently---row sums in a row-major array. The proposed solution in the question only needs to replace `totalcol += anArray[row][col]` with `totalcol += anArray[col][row]` and would already work for this case.

It is a bit more difficult to compute column sums in a row-major array, or---again equivalently---row sums in a column-major array. The rest of this answer shows how to compute column sums for a row-major array. In this case, `anArray.length` is the number of rows, and `anArray[i].length` is the number of columns in row `i`.

---

In the more usual case where all your rows have the same number of columns, you could do this:

```
int numrows = anArray.length;
int numcols = (numrows > 0) ? anArray[0].length : 0; // Guard against 0x0 array

for(int col = 0; col < numcols; col++) {
    int totalcol = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < numrows; row++) {
        totalcol += anArray[row][col];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + totalcol);
}
```

---

If your rows may each have a different number of columns (as suggested by the question title), you need to:

1. Determine when there are no more columns to sum over.
2. When computing the sum of column `col`, make sure to skip rows that are too short

One way would be:

```
int numrows = anArray.length;

for(int col = 0; /* not known a priori*/; col++) {
    int totalcol = 0;
    boolean emptySum = true; // At first, assume no rows are long enough
    for(int row = 0; row < numrows; row++) {
        if(anArray[row].length <= col ) continue; // Skip short row
        emptySum = false; // Mark assumption as wrong
        totalcol += anArray[row][col];
    }

    // Exit the loop if we did not sum anything, i.e. no row had a column with index col
    if(emptySum) break;

    System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + totalcol);
}
```

---

Instead of using the awkward `emptySum` flag to quit the loop, you could determine the *maximal* column length in a preliminary pass:

```
int numrows    = anArray.length;
int maxnumcols = (numrows > 0) ? anArray[0].length : 0; // Guard against 0x0 array

for(int row = 1; row < numrows; row++) {
    maxnumcols = Math.max(maxnumcols, anArray[row].length);
}

for(int col = 0; col < maxnumcols; col++) {
    int totalcol = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < numrows; row++) {
        if(anArray[row].length <= col) continue; // Skip short row
        totalcol += anArray[row][col];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + totalcol);
}
```

---

Finally, if you are allowed to store the sums (instead of immediately outputting them), this would be an even cleaner solution (note the row-major order of iteration, which fits nicely to the row-major order of the array itself):

```
int numrows    = anArray.length;
int maxnumcols = (numrows > 0) ? anArray[0].length : 0; // Guard against 0x0 array

for(int row = 1; row < numrows; row++) {
    maxnumcols = Math.max(maxnumcols, anArray[row].length);
}

int[] colsums = new int[maxnumcols]; // In Java, all elements are initialized to zero

for(int row = 0; row < numrows; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < anArray[row].length; col++) {
        colsums[col] += anArray[row][col];
    }
}

for(int col = 0; col < colsums.length; col++) {
    System.out.println("Sum of column " + col + " = " + colsums[col]);
}
```